# Merge [chosen] and [jquery-chosen] tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

The [chosen](/questions/tagged/chosen) and [jquery-chosen](/questions/tagged/jquery-chosen) tags both refer to the same thing: the [jquery chosen plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/).

I think they should be merged, but I do not have the privileges to do so.

Comment: I think *chosen* seems to be the one to stay, what do you think?

Comment: `[jquery-chosen]` is arguably more precise.

Comment: And what about using chosen with Prototype? If you read the wiki it's written "for jQuery **AND** prototype"

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I agree with Hugo, Chosen works for both Prototype & jQuery.

Comment: @j0k, maybe introduce `[prototype-chosen]` too? A good portion of the code is the same, but these are still two different implementations, and at least some questions may only pertain to one of them. `[chosen]` used alone sounds like a meta-tag IMHO.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That sounds good to me, since there is also a `mootools-chosen`: https://github.com/julesjanssen/chosen. There is only [one question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prototypejs+chosen) tagged with prototype + chosen and [none](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mootools+chosen) with mootools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've retagged question: [chosen](/questions/tagged/chosen) -> [jquery-chosen](/questions/tagged/jquery-chosen).

I've also created the [prototype-chosen](/questions/tagged/prototype-chosen) to be consistent (yes for just one question).

Aside that, I've also retagged (his cousin) [select2](/questions/tagged/select2) to [jquery-select2](/questions/tagged/jquery-select2).

Comment: Can you add the chosen.js tag as a synonym for jQuery-chosen?

Comment: @j08691 I cleaned the [tag:chosen.js] ;) It will be removed in few hours.